# How to use cluster and node.js to run both an HTTP and HTTPS server

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

So I have the following code in my `app.js` file:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
    // code
}).listen(80);

// var options = ...

https.createServer(options, function (request, response) {
   // code
}).listen(443);
```

How do I use cluster to run in a single process both the server objects?

Thanks

Comment: Since you're already going to have to think about how to run multiple instances of your web server (otherwise you wouldn't be using cluster), why do you want to run the http and https servers in a single worker?

Comment: If there are not performance issues on node, my architecture would be easier to manage when having both HTTP and HTTPS in one process.

Answer (score 0):

[Cluster API](http://www.nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) will actually run 2 servers as 2 processes. There question should sound "how to configure `connect` or `express` to listen to 2 ports"